# How do I build a VSTS project with an absolute-path reference folder?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have two projects in TFS, `WebSite` and `Reference`, and they follow the structure:

> $\
>
> - WebSite: Main project to be built
> - Reference: Repository with many referenceable dlls.

`Website.dll` uses dlls existing at `Reference` but, for several reasons, they are not contained in the same solution, and may be mapped to different folders that do not follow the VSTS structure.

So, in order to have the Website project compiling locally, the `Reference`'s.dlls `Hintpath` at `Website.csproj` have been manually changed to a specific, absolute path, common to all developers' machine.

Now, we're experiencing with CI/CD, and we're thrilled with the hypothesis of having VSTS doing the dirty, tedious work of building/deploying. Thing is, since Reference.dll is not in the same project as Website, building ends up lacking essential libraries (the aforementioned Reference folder) and fails.

Is there a way of telling VSTS to `GET` `Reference`'s dlls (which are compiled at this point), copy them to the directory `Website.csproj` is being built at and let them be used to build the main project?

What I've tried:

First:

> - Map Website and Reference in the `Get Sources` step
> - Using a `Copy Files` task, set `Source FOlder` as $\References and Target Folder as `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)`
> - Build

Now:

> - Added all the references in the main project.

In both cases, none of the references are found, and the

> The type or namespace name '(namespacehere)' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

errors are thrown.

I've been searching through the vsts help section, but can't seem to find any obvious solutions.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s mainly caused by **the Reference's dlls are not added in source control (TFVC repo)**.

First, please make sure you add the Reference's dlls into the website project. So the project file will contain the reference as below (`ClassLibrary1.dll` as the reference in below example):

```
<Reference Include="ClassLibrary1">
  <HintPath>..\..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\ClassLibrary1.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Then you can use any of below options to make the referenced dlls work.

#### Option 1: add the referenced dlls into source control

If you have added `.tfignore` file into your TFVC repo, it will ignore files and folders under `**\bin,` so the reference dlls not checkin to TFVC repo by default. You can follow below options to checkin the reference dlls into TFVC repo:

1. Exclude the reference dlls in `.tfignore`

   Exclude the dlls you want to refer in `.tfignore`. The format is:

   ```
   !**\referencename.dll
   ```

   Such as `!**\ClassLibrary1.dll`.
2. Add the reference dlls into source control

   In VS -> Source Control Explorer -> Add items to folder -> selected the dlls.

   [image]
3. Checkin and double check the dlls are added into TFVC repo

   In VS pending changes window, there will show the dlls and the `.tfignore` file as Inculded changes, checkin the changes.

   [image]

   And double check the dlls are added into TFVC repo in VSTS web page.

   [image]

#### Option 2: build the reference project before building website project

If you do not want to add the dlls into source control, you can also **build the reference solution firstly** so that the reference dlls will generate before build the website project. Details as below:

Edit build definition -> add VS Build task (specify reference solution) before building website project -> Save and queue the build.

**Note:** for option 2, the build configuration you specified in the relative path should be consistent with the build configuration in VSTS build definition.

Such as I specified `Debug` in the relative path `..\..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\ClassLibrary1.dll`. So in my VSTS build definition, VS build task to build the reference project, the build configuration must be `Debug`.

[image]

Now, no matter which option you are using, VSTS build will not show the error message `The type or namespace name '(namespacehere)' could not be found`.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer, @Marina. In case I decide for the second option, will both the projects generate binaries in the same output folder? Or do I have to execute a copy task to move files from a path to the other?

Comment: @EricWu the binary files will be generated under each project's `bin` folder separately. It's unnecessary to use Copy files tass since it's already defined to search the dll under the reference project (as the path `..\..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\ClassLibrary1.dll` in my example). And just for reminder: you should map all the projects in Get sources step, so just leave the local path empty (https://ibb.co/hSe3md), vsts build will get all the files from TFVC repo into `$(build.sourcesDirectory)`.

Comment: in that case, both projects must exist within the same solution, right?
In my scenario, the projects belong to different solutions. Is it still possible without joining them?

Comment: It's not necessary for all projects locate in same solution. It's ok for the projects belongs to different solutions? And have you build again, what's the result?

Comment: I have essentially built using the first approach, and it worked for all purposes (I've marked your answer as *the* answer because of that). Still, I'm curious about the second approach. If the projects are not within the same solution, does it mean they have to be referable through file system paths?

Comment: @EricWu The reason for failing to build with option2, it mainly cause the **build configuration** for VS Build task to build reference project is not same as the build configuration specified in relative path (I added the detail in under option 2). And if you prefer option 2, you can delete the dll in source control and test with option 2 again.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to approach this is to not store references in source control. Turn them into packages, store them in a package management feed, and restore them during build. Developers will automatically restore them on build.